# Is there any way I can use wildcards or a LIKE statement in Sql to identify usernames that follow this pattern in their name?

Tags: sql

This is just an SQL question regarding how you would for example identify users who had a username with the format: 
[Uppercase, Lowercase, Lowercase, Uppercase, and lowercase letters].  Examples, JudEjose, SyeDsaji, AbbAsode etc.

So a query might be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username ??????
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested on PostgreSQL 9.3:

```
select username from users where username ~ '[A-Z][a-z]{2}[A-Z][a-z]+';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE upper(Username) = upper('JudEjose');
```

It is for oracle, I'm not sure about other DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

case **sensitive** using this syntax :

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE WHERE Username LIKE '%Bb%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

case **insensitive** using this syntax :

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE WHERE Username LIKE '%Bb%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE Username = UPPER(Username) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```